# Video playback from SPO Document library

Tags: video

Noticed a few weeks back that Document and Picture libraries support what appears to be adaptive bitrate streaming video.  If an MP4 video is uploaded into a library, a user clicks on it and the video buffers for a second or two then starts playing in browser.  If you look using dev tools you can see that the video has been transcoded and is now being delivered in fragments instead of a MP4 aka old school progressive download.  Can someone confirm this new feature and tell me if there is a way to force SPO to respect the dimensions of the video and not scale it full screen?  Pictures display at their native size so something is not quite right.  Thanks!

Comment: Independent on how a Video works within a library, wouldn't you get an overall better experience by using O365 Video?

Comment: we are looking at options to O365.  Our model for using O365 is one that is open to all and as such we need alternatives for hosting private content.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but O365 videos is part of the O365 solution suite and it processes the videos to be seen at different rates depending on the network and won't use resources from the main site collection, definitely take a look into it =)

Comment: Yugo thanks for the reply. I was not clear in my last statement. We are already using O365 Video to host our video content. Our model is to keep our portal open to all within our enterprise and as such need an alternative for hosting private content. We don't want to get into managing private channels on O365 Video as we use AD Groups to control access which can be a timely and resource intensive process for us.